# Know if a user say something specific

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a discord bot, and there's a command that looks at the messages that the user sends in a specific channel. In this channel, we are only allowed to say "BLABLA". I've made a code that almost works, if I say something else than "BLABLA", the bot will remove the message, but if I say for example: "hey BLABLA" the message will not be removed.

Here's my code:

```
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.channel.id == "509789705651617793") {
    if (!msg.content.toLowerCase().includes("bla")) {
      msg.delete(1);
      msg.author.send('You can only send "BLABLA" in <#509789705651617793>');

      bot.channels
        .get(`576073035476631563`)
        .send(
          `${msg.author}, tried to send something else than "blabla" in <#509789705651617793>, his message was: ${msg.content}`
        )
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error("err");
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `"hey BLABLA".toLowerCase()` *does* `.includes("bla")`. If you need an exact match, don't use `.includes`.

Comment: so what can i use then ?

Comment: Maybe test for *equality*, `===`?

Comment: Yes, but the users can send "BLA" or "BLABLA" or "BLABLABLABLA", so I can't really test for equality

Comment: Perhaps look into regular expressions, then.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check the entire string of `message.content` for **BLABLA**

```
const saidBlaBla = message.content.toLowerCase()
   .includes('blabla');

if (!saidBlaBla) {
     msg.delete(1)
     msg.author.send('You can only send "BLABLA" in <#509789705651617793>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Regular Expressions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and allow only the letters `b`, `B`, `l`, `L`, `a`, `A` to be sent, along with [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to make sure that the message starts with "BLA".

```js
const RegEx = /^[BbLlAa]+$/

// Checking if the message contains any other character except b, B, l, L, a, A.
if (!message.content.match(RegEx)) {message.delete(); return message.author.send("You can only say BLABLA.");};

// Checking if the message starts with BLA.
if (!message.content.startsWith("BLA")) {message.delete(); return message.author.send("You can only say BLABLA.")};
```

---

Another method is to check if the message equals "BLABLA".

```js
if (message.content !== "BLABLA") {message.delete(); return message.author.send("You can only say BLABLA.")};
```

Comment: Note that a pipe in a character class `[a|b]` is just a literal pipe character. It does **not** mean "or", that's what the character class already means.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've modified the RegEx.